# SWIFT 3 - MTLResourceOptions.cpuCacheModeDefaultCache

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, metal

I have this error 'cpuCacheModeDefaultCache' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set.

[image]

Comment: Then do what the error message tells you to do. :) Do `options: []`. And look for doc about "option set", it will be clear very fast.

Comment: Of course remove options that is fast way, I would like to understand problem for cpuCacheModeDefaultCache. Why cpuCacheModeDefaultCache is not working ?

Comment: Because cpuCacheModeDefaultCache is the *default* option, which is the same as passing no option. And the property was changed for Swift 3. Everything is working as expected, it's just that some syntax has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do [] which is the default behavior. if you want use some specific option .. should use something like :

```
MTLResourceOptions(rawValue: UInt(MTLResourceCPUCacheModeShift))
// or
MTLResourceOptions(rawValue: UInt(MTLCPUCacheMode.defaultCache.rawValue))
```